# Selecting a range on double click event?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I do that, under the *BeforeDoubleClick* event, that if the user double clicks on a cell, it will select the cells from the row 11 to row 57.

If it is possible, can I set it to only work in a column range "L" to "S"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

'change Range to suit your needs
If Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Then Range("L11:S57").Select

End Sub
```

If you want entire rows type `Rows("11:57").Select` For entire columns, type `Columns("L:S").Select`